# Angularfire nosql query using relational foreign keys setup

Tags: angularjs, foreign-keys, relational-database, angularfire, nosql

I have been having a great deal of difficulty trying to do a relational query through firebase using angular.

```
        var userChallengeRef=new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+ 'users/'+$rootScope.currentUser.$id+'/mychallenges');
        var userChallengeInfo=$firebaseArray(userChallengeRef)
        // var log = [];

        // var challUserRef=challengesRef

        // challUserRef.orderByChild("participants").equalTo($rootScope.currentUser.$id).on("child_added", function(snapshot){

        // })
        // var challUserInfo=$firebaseArray(challUserRef);




        $scope.mychallenges=[];
        // angular.forEach(userChallengeRef, function(value, key) {
        //   // this.push(key + ': ' + value);
        //   var temp=new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+ 'challenges/'+value);
        //   $scope.mychallenges.push(temp)
        // }, log);
        userChallengeInfo.$loaded()
        .then(function(){
            angular.forEach(userChallengeInfo, function(userChallengeInfo) {
                // console.log(userChallengeInfo);
                // console.log(userChallengeInfo.$id);
                var tempRef=new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+ 'challenges/'+userChallengeInfo.$id)
                var temp=$firebaseArray(tempRef);
                console.log(userChallengeInfo.role)
                temp.$loaded().then(function(){
                  console.log(temp.name)
                })
                // console.log(temp);


                // $scope.mychallenges.push(temp);
                  $scope.mychallenges.push({
                        id: userChallengeInfo.$id,
                        name: 'test object',
                        name2: 'temp.$name'
                        date: temp.date,
                        role: temp.challengeParticipant.role,*/

                  })
            })
            console.log($scope.mychallenges);

        });
```

I have tried so many different ways to no success. The temp shows up as a weird object. I want to generate an angular array by only inputing in the objects from the firebase array foreach loop that have the userid. I am then using an ng-repeat to make it work. I'd rather not use a filter because this method is much faster if the database gets large. However, I am open to any suggestions on best practice.

If my relational firebasearray implentation of mychallenges worked correctly like the "userChallengeInfo" array it would display like this in the log:

```
Object {date: 1455391999128, role: "Participant", $id: "-KAHXgh5_j-4PPnyjNP4", $priority: null}
```

Note I do not really want to use a firebase array when doing this because I want this to be a temporary local object not stored on the database.

Comment: Why don't you simply `var userChallengeRef=new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+ 'users/'+$rootScope.currentUser.$id+'/mychallenges'); 
userChallengeRef.once('value', function(snapshot) { console.log(snapshot.val()); });` You can if needed loop over the children/challenged with [`snapshot.forEach()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/foreach.html).

Comment: I am trying to use the ids from the mychallenges in the current user to access challenge information from the challenges/ table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: After some different experiments I have discovered that if I change the

```
var temp=$firebaseObject(tempRef);
```

Then I can push it into the angular local array to correctly call the different attributes. Now I can call the attributes of the temp like temp.name.

I guess that I can't push the firebasearray to the angular array but I can push firebaseobject onto it. I know that firebasearray typically updates the database automatically when the object needs to call the save method.